# Implement the Selenium library Python for a website backend

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to implement selenium in a code of a backend of a website we’re building.

I am building a website that scraps data from several websites using Python as a backend so I would like to know

Comment: Yes, you can run it in headless mode. However, this question is not clear enough.

Comment: I am building a website and in this website there is specified data displayed. I want to scrap these data's from another website using selenium and Beautiful soup and display it in my website.

Answer (score 0):

scrape the data and store it in a database. And then display that scraped data from the database.
Run scraping in a scheduled way to update your data.

Answer (score 0):

[ScrapyRT](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt)
You can use this.

This helps you to scrape data and returns you a http response(that's data) which you can you display in your website